# Colour problem: floor too dark

Tags: rendering, color

I changed my Blender version from 3.2 to 2.92 for a project.
When I rendered my scene in 3.2, I had no problems.

However in 2.92 I have that:
[image]

The floor is too dark. I'd like something a bit brighter.

My texturing node is:
[image]

Does someone know why the floor is so dark and how to fix that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I share the document at this address: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9aqmyDQW" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9aqmyDQW/)

Comment: thanks but you first need to pack the images, maybe share just the floor

Comment: How I can send you the images?
With the previous link I can only share blender files (.bleng)

Comment: pack the images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and use https://workupload.com

Comment: Thanks. You can download the images here https://workupload.com/archive/Tb67zEmt

Comment: I've downloaded 2.92 to test it but it makes it crash, I hope someone will tell

Comment: I am sorry to hear about that.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem. It is on the normal map!
In the 3.2 version, I assume, the normal map and the deplacement map can be connected as shown in the following picture
[image]

However, this does not really work in the version 2.92, and makes the texture looking darkest.

The correct connexion is the one shown in the following image
[image]

Comment: Both connection set ups are wrong, but the first one more so. In it, there is a Normal vector being plugged into the height input of a Displacement, then that vector is plugged into the Normal input of the BSDF. Why is the displacement node even there? The second node tree fixes that, but both trees have image color being fed directly into a Normal Vector input, when they should be converted with a Normal Map node first. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Even for the displacement map?
I found an the internet the same connect then on the second image.
Moreover, they are not image color, but normal and displacement maps.

Comment: What comes out of the node is a Color  value, wether it is meant to be used as a Normal  vector map or not. As mentioned, it needs to be converted with a Normal Map node, as is properly used for the material Normals in the second tree. Implicit conversion to a vector does not generate an error (Blender can do it), but it leaves the intended vector offset in all positive directions, and with improperly scaled strengths.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the correction. I did not know that.